# angular ui-carousel with thumbnails

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, carousel

I have the following html code that renders an angular ui-bootstrp carousel:

```
<div class="slider" uib-carousel active="active" interval="myInterval" >
     <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
         <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}">
     </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="margin-top">
          <div ng-repeat="slide in thumbnails">
               <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" ng-click="setActive(slide.id)">
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

and the setActive function is:

```
$scope.thumbnails = $scope.slides.slice((0,5);

$scope.setActive = function(idx) {
  $scope.active=idx;
}
```

When I click on the thumbnails the slider correctly shows the selected image. However, as soon as I click on the carousel arrows, the ng-click of the thumbnails stops working (the function is called by angular but the carousel does not slide to the selected image). How can I fix this?